# C# Table Data Annotation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is the difference between `[Table("table_name"), Schema = "schema_name"]` and `[Table("schema_name.table_name")]` ways of providing data annotation over a class.?
Can you confirm the second option will work?

Answer (score 1):

You should use it llike this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("StudentMaster", Schema="Admin")]
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
``
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But will the second approach work, as I am going through existing code and it is present like the second approach, but couldn't find any documentation on the same.

Comment: i never seen it like that, and as you say it is not documented anywhere, I would not do it like that. Stick with standards.